# How to save the ouput of shell command into a text file in VBA 

Tags: vba, excel, ftp

I have my code written like this,

```
  function ftpsend()

  Dim vPath As String
  Dim vFile As String
  Dim vFTPServ As String
  Dim fNum As Long
  Dim currntdir As String

  currntdir = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"


 vPath = currntdir
 vFile = currntdir & "abc.xml"
 vFTPServ = "ftp.abc.com" 

  'Mounting file command for ftp.exe
  fNum = FreeFile()
 Open vPath & "abc.txt" For Output As #fNum
 Print #1, "USER student" 
 Print #1, "xxxxx"
 Print #1, "send " & vFile  
 Print #1, "close" 
 Print #1, "quit" 
 Close


 Shell "ftp -n -i -g -s:" & vPath & "abc.txt  " & vFTPServ, vbNormalFocus

 end function
```

Now, the shell command displays the output in the console ftp.exe as

```
Connected to ftp.abc.com
220 Microsoft FTP service
ftp>USER student
230 User logged in 
ftp>send D:abc.xml
200 PORT command successful
226 Transfer Complete 
ftp>close
221>Good bye
ftp>
```

I want this output from console as it is copied into a text file.Because,sometimes when the username and password are incorrect, it displays the message as " User not logged in ", "Login failed" in the console.I want to handle that error.Any other way to handle ftp errors? Please Help...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
Shell "ftp -n -i -g -s:" & vPath & "abc.txt  " & vFTPServ, vbNormalFocus
```

by

```
Shell "ftp -n -i -g -s:" & vPath & "abc.txt  " & vFTPServ & " > test.txt", vbNormalFocus
```

or

```
Shell "ftp -n -i -g -s:" & vPath & "abc.txt  " & vFTPServ & " >> test.txt", vbNormalFocus
```

`>` or `>>` diverts console output to a file.  Both `>` and `>>` will create `test.txt` if it does not exist.  `>` will delete an existing text.txt while `>>` will append the new output to the existing contents of `test.txt`.

Comment: sorry!! It didnt work.It is just placing only the line "ftp>" in the test.txt file.All my output is not copied to the text file.Any other solution please!!

Comment: Are you using `>`?  Having thought about your output, my guess is that each line counts as a separate output.  With `>` each line would delete the existing file and create a new one.  Result `test.txt` only contains the last line "ftp>".  Try `>>`.

Comment: Tried with both combinations '>' and '>>'. Gave in this way

Shell "ftp.exe -n -i -g -s:" & vPath & "\abc.txt " & vFTPServ & " >> Test.txt", vbNormalFocus

Same output results for both of them.Could not find the reason why only last line is getting copied!

Comment: Sorry but I have no further suggestions. I have never used divert with ftp but use it successfully with a number of other programmes that output to the console. The only difference I can see is that I do not use Shell. Instead I create a batch file containing 100s of commands and divert all their console output to a text file. Sudden idea. Is `>` an escape character for Shell so `>>` is being converted to `>`? You could try `>>>>`. You could also try creating a batch file containing the ftp command and see if that works.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true.   Also make sure you know where the output file is being created (eg. Use the full path)