# Record in a .txt file the generated results of an .exe

Tags: excel, vba, shell

I have and Excel file which contains the data for a Python code. Python code is called from a .exe, and I can see in the PowerShell the results which that code is generating.

```
Sub Button()
    Dim strPName As String
    Dim strData As String

    strPName = Range("H24").Text
    strData = "--inputs"

    Call Shell("""" & strPName & """ """ & strData & """", vbNormalFocus)

End Sub
```

When I have issues in the code or with the data input, the PowerShell is switch off and I cannot review which was the issue. 
I want to include in the button code an automatic .txt file generation, which records the PowerShell text and let me review it after the stop.

I found here [How to save the ouput of shell command into a text file in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527201/how-to-save-the-ouput-of-shell-command-into-a-text-file-in-vba)  the following command:

```
Shell "ftp -n -i -g -s:" & vPath & "abc.txt  " & vFTPServ & " >> test.txt", vbNormalFocus
```

But I don't know how to connect it properly in my current button.

Could you give me some suggestions of how could I solve it?

Comment: You just put the `" >> test.txt"` at the end of the string...

Comment: Could you give me some approach about the final string?`Call Shell("""" & strPName & """ """ & strData & """" & " >> test.txt", vbNormalFocus) `???

Comment: assuming your code without it shows what you want on the screen, then that should work.