# Keep PowerShell console open from a VBA .exe execution

Tags: excel, vba, exe

I want to keep open the PowerShell console once the execution has finished.

Actually, after the .exe execution, the PowerShell shut down. I would like to review the outputs once the execution stops, but I can't with the current code.

```
Sub Button_run_st()
    Dim strPName As String
    Dim strA As String

    strPName = Range("C14").Text
    strA = "--dd=" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

    Call Shell("" & strPName & " " & strA & "", vbNormalNoFocus)

End Sub
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: https://blog.danskingdom.com/keep-powershell-console-window-open-after-script-finishes-running/

Comment: The problem is that I'm running the .exe from a button in Excel, because I have some information which is needed there. I need to include in the macro the -NoExit. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Wouldnt it make more sense to pipe the output from it into a text file that you can then read with excel when it is done? (and that link shows you how to add -NoExit to it.

Comment: Yes, and I would prefer that, but the last post [.txt file from .exe results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60185955/record-in-a-txt-file-the-generated-results-of-an-exe) doesn't work so I thought that stop the Shell could be easier

Comment: If it doesn't work, then that means there is a problem with the way you are trying to do it. I just tested it on my end, and it worked just fine.